# How to create the layout of Google Plus App without any sacrifices on Performance?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, client-server, google-plus

What I want to try and accomplish is:

1. In the main layout the app should wait for server response and then populate the screen with an initially certain number of smaller layouts(or whatever those card layouts are referred to), ie I would like to understand how to dynamically create each card, based on the server response .ie if server sends only 2 card details user gets 2 cards and likewise.
2. Then the above should load upto a certain max number of cards(like upto a max of 5 or 6) and the rest should be loaded on user action like "swipe-up".

I have done a lot of reading and have come to certain conclusions like for the first one I think I have to use an Adapter and Listview to dynamically populate the screen (but I am not sure),I would try and like to do is create a small relative layout nested with textviews and imageview(just like google cards), and maybe for the second one setup some kind of swipe action listener.

I am a noob at this and I would like some guidance regarding this matter, I am not sure about how to start and that's why i havent posted any worked-on code, any tips guidances and links to examples and tutorials will be highly appreciated.

Comment: My question is put On Hold..could somebody suggest some ways to improve this to match the community standards and so would be useful for others? As for my problem I did a lot of research and reached assumptions which I was completely unsure of and thankfully which was confirmed by Booger and thereby has lead me to understand more about View Holder and Async Loading which took away worries about performance.

Comment: My second demand was mainly made because I was worried about performance, but thankfully the View Holder and Async Loading concepts will definitely compensate for the issue and understanding how ListView recycle views will also be a great help to anybody reading this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by creating a simple Listview, using an Adapter (which you will populate using a Layout of your creation).  Exactly like you said ;-).  This is a very common task in Android, and knowing how to do this is the base of a lot in Android.  I am pretty sure G+ uses ListViews with custom Adapters (hint: exactly what you describe).

Worry about styling the cards, and adding swipe gestures next (that is something you will "tack on" after you have the basic ListView working.

Comment: Wow atleast its reassuring to know that my assumptions aren't totally idiotic and thanks for your insight, I will follow your advice and work on getting a basic ListView working and then worry about the rest(I already have enough ideas and codes for the card styling though) just need to worry about and keep the gesture thingy for last. Since you are already a android veteran could you please suggest some tutorials or books which might guide me?

Comment: Search SO, there was just a thread about book suggestions.